# RavenDB facet on list values

Tags: ravendb, faceted-search

Is faceting on the values of a list possible?  I can query off of them in the index but it doesn't look like facets are returning any values.  Here is a test:
https://gist.github.com/svickers/5a29a4e32a24b1576ae3#file-ravenfacets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See answer for this in the mailing list.

http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/6e7b4e8393536d1f/2f10ab3a63b86148?lnk=gst&q=Faceting+on+list+values#2f10ab3a63b86148